# How to make these boxes on this image text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was given this image of the human body:

[image: Human body photo]

I was tasked with making the different boxes text boxes. Now I could just go through the process of making a bunch of text boxes and setting their placements using position: absolute and then just moving them wherever. The problem is that I need to do this multiple times and in different positions. I was wondering if there would be a way to make this more efficient than that. I'm using React and css to make this so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, you'll still need to specify the relative placement of each element. So I don't see how anything could be more efficient than absolute positioning. Now, you could put the coordinates in an array, loop through it, and create an element at each of those coordinates, but you'll still have to calculate the coordinates in advance.

Comment: @kmoser Yeah that's what I assumed. Thank you for confirming that for me